# How to fix the error 'This server version is not supported. only servers up to microsoft sql server 2008 are supported'?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 in my dev machine. I am ujsing Visual Studio 2010 with SP1.

After installing SQL Server 2012 I am no longer able to work with project local MDF files, I get the message

```
This server version is not supported. only servers up to microsoft sql server 
2008 are supported" when i try to work with them.
```

This problem has been reported for earlier versins ov SQL / Visual Studio but I have not found a way to fix this for **SQL 2012**. Does anyone have a fix or workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Visual Studio's error "This server version is not supported..." for SQL Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285652/how-to-fix-visual-studios-error-this-server-version-is-not-supported-for-s)

Answer (score 0):

since the `Visual Studio 2010` was released prior to `SQL Server 2012` you cannot work with local MDF files or any design time stuffs involving the sql server.

However you can work with `SQL Server 2012` by establishing sql connection in code.