# This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

For some days I am a little desperate about a problem in Visual Studio 2008, what happens is that in my company I work with VS 2008 and SQL Server 2014, I have worked normally but when choosing a new connection in a DataSet (Example: when I want to add a DataGridView with data from the database I have to do it by means of the code and not by the VS designer to add connections) I have the following error:

[image]

Yes, I installed two or three times the update for Visual Studio 2008 [**Service Pack 1**](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/21/sql-server-2008-fix-connection-error-with-visual-studio-2008-server-version-is-not-supported/) followed by restarting the computer several times and getting absolutely nothing, I also chose to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on my computer and does not solve the problem can anyone Orient me and is it possible to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You're using ancient versions of *everything*. Why VS2008? That's not even a supported product.

Comment: The project that you are working on is very robust and has been developing for many years in Visual Studio 2008 ...

Comment: does this help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285652/how-to-fix-visual-studios-error-this-server-version-is-not-supported-for-s

Comment: Well, you can't stay on VS 2008 forever.  Have you tried moving to Visual Studio 2017?  You can still target .NET 3.5 with modern versions of VS.

Comment: Believe me that I also suggested that change, but it is difficult, in some modules of the project there are reports (Report .NET) that at the moment of migration do not work, one of my bosses told me that there have been several attempts but has not been Possible, in any case I consider that the use of these technologies so old will allow the emergence of much worse problems with the passage of time

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

I think the most efficient solution to this problem is to move the project to a newer technology, this would avoid headaches in the future.

However a temporary and somewhat "disgusting" solution is:

- Having SQL Server [**2008 R2 Service Pack 2 SP2**](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=30438)
- Restore the database (SQL Server 2014) in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2
- In VS 2008 you would choose to connect to the instance of SQL Server
  2008 R2 SP2 and work locally

If this does not work then try to install [**Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2**](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=26727) and restart the computer

For now I will have to adapt to the second solution jejeje

Thank you very much to all!